# Using Eclipselink (MOXy) with SoapHandler will strip CDATA tags

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, eclipselink, cdata, moxy

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) has the @XmlCDATA annotation for handling CDATA.

When using Moxy and annotating a String value such as

```
@XmlCDATA
private String payload;
```

If I run this web service it will work and display with CDATA tags after being processed by JAXB (I do not have control over JAXB processing except through annotations so this is helpful).

As soon as I add an annotation to to call a HandlerChain file e.x.

```
@HandlerChain(file = "/META-INF/handler-chain.xml")
```

I will lose my CDATA tags!  This particular handler implements SOAPHandler.  I've been experimenting and playing around with it but can not get it to keep the CDATA tags.  It's as if it's being formatted in the handleMessage() method.  Even if this method does nothing, such as return false; or return true; It still loses CDATA tags.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'm confused.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: +1 - As the MOXy lead I'm not sure if there is any input I can offer as from your question MOXy is creating the CDATA sections correctly.  I've edited your question to include the "jax-ws" and "web-services" tags to expand the audience.  Which application server are you running in?

Comment: The question is can this be fixed.  It's more on the end of a SOAPHandler issue perhaps.  To work around, we are simply not using SOAPHandler.  But keep running into other issues where we'd like to edit the response in a SOAPHandler but having MOXy annotation is more important.  I am running in Websphere App Server 7.